# jQuery - load events - Forward / Back

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, event-handling, turbolinks

I have certain functions that I have to load after the css have fully loaded, (custom fonts) in order for them to work correctly.

One of them is centering text vertically in boxes.

```
        $(y).css({
            'padding-top' : padding_top + 'px',
            'visibility' : 'visible'
        });
```

I'm using turbolinks.js for faster loading between the pages and for the functions to work correctly I added this

```
$(window).bind('page:change', do_on_load);
function do_on_load(){
    functions...
}
```

When clicking between the pages I get the result I want, however when moving back/forward this event runs to "fast" and I all I receive is 0 when calculating an elements height and such.

Is there a solution for this, such as an event I can bind to?

Comment: According to the documentation: "If you have DOM transformation that are not idempotent (the best way), you can hook them to happen only on page:load instead of page:change (as that would run them again on the cached pages)." Have you tried that?

Comment: @jaudette - You're certainly right, thx a bunch!! ;)